# Android WebRTC DataChannel binary transfer mode

Tags: android, file, webrtc, file-transfer, rtcdatachannel

I achieved to transfer data between two android phones using WebRTC's `DataChannel` :

On one side, I send the data:

```
boolean isBinaryFile = false;
File file = new File(path); // let's assume path is a .whatever file's path (txt, jpg, pdf..) 
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(convertFileToByteArray(file));
DataChannel.Buffer buf = new DataChannel.Buffer(byteBuffer, isBinaryFile); 
dataChannel.send(buf);
```

On the other side, this callback should be called regardless of `isBinaryFile` value :

```
public void onMessage( final DataChannel.Buffer buffer ){
    Log.e(TAG, "Incomming file on DataChannel");

    ByteBuffer data = buffer.data;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[ data.capacity() ];
    data.get(bytes);

    // If it's not a binary file (text)
    if( !buffer.binary ) {
        String strData = new String( bytes );
        Log.e(TAG, "Text file is : " + strData);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Received binary file ! :)");
    }
}
```

In the case of any file, when `isBinaryFile` is **false**, the callback is called and I'm able to print the text, or even reconstruct the file (images, pdf, whatever).

When `isBinaryFile` is **true** I get the following error:

```
Warning(rtpdataengine.cc:317): Not sending data because binary type is unsupported.
```

After reading [this](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=2253), looks like I need to use `SCTP DataChannels`, but I don't know how !

Comment: How did you register `onMessage` callback?

Comment: Sorry I'm late. Just `implements DataChannel.Observer`.

Comment: Can you help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499725/new-peerconnectionfactory-gives-error-on-android ? Or can you please share a sample code which sends file from one android to other.. Just an example code which helps in understanding the way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution !

Before, I constructed my `PeerConnection` with `RtpDataChannels` constraint to `true`; but to use **SCTP DataChannels**, you must let it to default (or set it to false), like this:

```
MediaConstraints pcConstraints = signalingParameters.pcConstraints;
// pcConstraints.optional.add(new KeyValuePair("RtpDataChannels", "false"));
pcConstraints.optional.add(new KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));
pc = factory.createPeerConnection(signalingParameters.iceServers,
            pcConstraints, pcObserver);
```

Simple ! :-)

Comment: how do you create dataChannel? Is your code available anywhere?

Comment: Would you please guide me to a tutorial on how to transfer files between two androids using webRTC ! thanks