# Send file from android to javascript using RTC

Tags: javascript, android, webrtc, file-transfer, rtcdatachannel

I have a little question, how i could implements an Android app using RTC and send to an Javascript server.

I've saw [Android WebRTC DataChannel binary transfer mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558153/android-webrtc-datachannel-binary-transfer-mode/28563091#28563091)

But i've no idea to how implement an DataChannel

Is there a tutorial to implement an WebRTC / RTC in android ? and create an channel that i could retrieve in Javascript nodeJS ?

Comment: Maybe this might help https://sipjs.com/download/ ?

Comment: This isn't working in android, i'm not abe to get this work on my AndroidApp to send it in my nodeJS client